# Display 1k as 1000 in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i hav started ags very newly, i need an overview on how to carry out the folowing task.
displaying
1k as 1000
1.2k as 1200
1l as 100000
and so on for any given dynamic input number.

Please help out, thanx in advance

Comment: Write a angular `filter`, but it will still require you to do some mathematics.

Comment: logically am able to do this in javascript. i m struggling to do it in ajs. am all new to ags......if possible can you provide any small samples on this task....any help is appreciated ...thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here is a filter example ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GWbtiz8UGvqF4S4OMl3X?p=preview)):

```
.filter('toNumber', function($filter) {

  var numberFilter = $filter('number');

  var dict = {
    k: 1000,
    l: 100000
  };

  var regex = /^([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)([kl])$/;

  return function(val, fraction) {
    var match;
    if(angular.isString(val) && (match = val.match(regex)) ) {
      val = match[1] * dict[match[2]];
    }

    return numberFilter(val, fraction || 0);

  };
});
```

Use it like so:

```
{{ '1k' | toNumber }}
```

Comment: ilan very sorry to bug u, can provide me the entire code if possible? i have jus startd ajs yest......n have this task deadline today....help would be appreciated very much

Comment: @Techhub an example http://plnkr.co/edit/GWbtiz8UGvqF4S4OMl3X?p=preview

Comment: thnx a ton llan...the program wrks greatt....jus one more help.... hw can we dynmcly get input from the user using input box..and with tht input use the same function

Comment: @Techhub I'm not sure I understand what you ask.

Comment: your program is very correct... but you have hardcoded the  values here  ... Ex  :- 1k -> {{ '1k' | toNumber }               I want it as...... user gives input when the application is run ---- any random number 5k , 9k etc and it converts and displays the result ....i.e dynamically getting input in an inputbox during runtime and giving the output.